# MY first vue js code not working with simple html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

someone kindly help me this code is not working i don't know whats wrong with this. i am using an external js file named app.js for vue js code in and index.html file.

index.html code

```js
new vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'my first vue js'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Vue Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what server you are using in order to "view the html" ?

Comment: I think your template needs to be part of the vue component not in your html file.

Comment: content of `el` ... i.e the div with id app in your case is replaced by .... nothing - as you have no template

Comment: check console for error and then post your error as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this Problem once,
you wrote in your app.js `new vue ({el:'#app', data:{ name: 'my first vue js' }});`

you just have to write `new vue` in capital letter like so `new Vue ({el:'#app', data:{ name: 'my first vue js' }});`

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in **index.html**

```
new vue({
el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'my first vue js'
  }
});
```

to

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
      data: {
        name: 'my first vue js'
      }
    });
```